# Add Picture file and href link to SP List in Header

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

How can I merge the two sets of code below so they show together in the Header?

**Picture File for Header:**

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "max-width": "100%"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/blabitty/Shared%20Documents/StepUpAwardAppHeader_v6.png"
  }
}
```

**and then under the picture have the text that is clickable link to guidelines for submission:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "*Step Up Program Award Guidelines",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-blue",
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/blabitty/shared%20documents/step%20up%20program%20award%20guidelines.png?web=1"
    },
    "style": {
        "font-size": "24px"
    }
}
```

**So that when they go to submit a new entry it looks like the demo below:**

Final view I am looking for:

[image: Final view looking for]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON formatting on list form for header layout. You can use JSON like:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "text-align": "center"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "max-width": "100%"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "src": "https://picsum.photos/500/200"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "*Step Up Program Award Guidelines",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-blue",
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/blabitty/shared%20documents/step%20up%20program%20award%20guidelines.png?web=1"
            },
            "style": {
                "font-size": "24px"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)